# Divorced input line in GNU Screen

Tags: shell, terminal, gnu-screen, telnet

Is it possible to divorce my input from the overall shell using Screen?  What I'm aiming for is akin to a status line that expands if I type more than would fit within a single line and is 'submitted'/'sent' to the shell when I press enter.

I'm looking to put together a simple configuration to use as a MUSH/MUD/MUCK/MOO client using screen+telnet.  The current issue with using telnet is that data sent from the remote server is inserted at the cursor position, which sucks badly if you're typing a lengthy paragraph.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Do you mean that the server can send data at any time, unlike the usual shell interaction model where you're either typing a command (at a prompt) or receiving command output (between prompts)?

Comment: Indeed; if you telnet into a raw TCP/IP service (esp. one that is multi-user like a MUSH), then as you are typing the server may send additional text to you which will get inserted at the cursor, part-way through what you are typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good architecture would be to divide the screen into two windows, one for command input and one for program display. That's basically what a normal MUD client would do. You can do that in Screen with the `split` command (`C-a S`).

Create a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) to transmit your input from the input window to the telnet window: `mkfifo mud-input-fifo`. In one of the windows, run `telnet mud.example.com 1234 <mud-input-fifo` or `nc mud.example.com 1234 <mud-input-fifo` (`nc` is [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), the Swiss Army knife of networking). In the other window, run `rlwrap tee mud-input-fifo` ([rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/rlwrap.html) provides line edition to any line input program).

Emacs could do that too. But you'd end up implementing a MUD client in Emacs, which has been done before ([`mu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/mu.el), [`mud.el`](http://www.waider.ie/hacks/emacs/mud.html), [`mudel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/mudel.el), [eMUDs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/eMUDs), …).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you are asking, but on many systems (including linux and most BSDs) you can set a key for the "rprnt" action:

```
 stty rprnt '^R'
```

and pressing the key while in a program that is using the tty driver for input processing [which I think telnet does when you are connected to a raw service like this] will cause the input line to redisplay on the next line

So your screen will look like:

```
SERVER PROMPT> your text your text your text your textOUTPUT FROM SERVER^R
your text your text your text your text your text_
```

Beyond that, you'll need to get a real MUD client like tinyfugue.